# Positioning of Views from bottom as well as top in RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a very simple layout with two `TextViews` one below the other and below these `TextViews` I have three horizontally aligned `ImageViews`.

I am being able to relatively place these views when settings positions below each other and specifying the top margin. But for the three `ImageViews`, I want to be able to set margin from the bottom of the screen. Unfortunately, I've not been able to achieve this using the `RelativeLayout`.

What I want to ask the experts is if it is possible at all? Do I need to  Following is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:textSize="250sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dividerTop"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="115sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/dividerTop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_random"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_below="@id/dividerTop"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_below="@id/dividerTop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dividerBottom"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your margins unit are wrong, you use scale points (sp) instead of densitiy independent pixel (dp). And you can try "alignParentBottom=true" on the image views.

Comment: That i already tried but was giving errors because couldnt find the ids. Now fixed and have posted as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured out myself. The Views need to be added in the order you want to position it from bottom and cannot be in the sequence they appear on screen. Following is the updated layout and works exactly as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:textSize="250sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/txtItemSmall"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />



    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_random"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dividerTop"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the ImageViews with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Then use 
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

```
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

        <ImageView
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Three of your ImageViews inside a Horizonntal Linear Layout and Align Linear Layout to Bottom Parent and set Margin_Bottom

```
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="64sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_below="@id/dividerTop"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_marginbottom="50dp" > <-- your own offset from bottom --!>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_random"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hiii"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_width="300sp"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Hiiii2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="250sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/btnRandom"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_random" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="64sp"
        android:layout_height="64sp"
        android:layout_above="@id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRandom"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And use **dp** instead of **sp** for margins.